# PDO fetchColumn() method return false

Tags: php, pdo

I am a complete php beginner, so the question is I guess really obvious, but I cannot find my solution anywhere so far. I am making a login box connected to a MySQL database. When I try to assign ID to the ID from the selected column nothing is assigned. Suggestions why ?

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
    /*** $message = a message saying we have connected ***/

    /*** set the error mode to excptions ***/
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /*** prepare the select statement ***/
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT email, password, ID FROM sta402_users
                WHERE email = :email AND password = :password");

    /*** bind the parameters ***/
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);



    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $stmt->execute();

    /*** check for a result ***/
    $ID = $stmt->fetchColumn(2);


    /*** if we have no result then fail boat ***/
    if($ID == false)
    {
        $message = 'Login Failed';
    }
```

I keep getting to the Login Failed message..

Comment: I can't exactly understand where to check for an extra white space. If I echo $email and $password they are both printed fine.

Comment: Are you perhaps hashing the password and is the result / original more than 40 characters? Why are you limiting it anyway?

Comment: Can you run the query directly in mysql (giving it the actual user and password, ie:  WHERE email = 'foo@bar.com' and password = 's3cr3t' ..)  Reason I ask is because the password is most likely hashed.  Perhaps using mysql `PASSWORD()` or md5, but no way for us to know that based on this

Comment: Good point, I just removed the limit because it is encrypted but ID is still not getting any value..

Comment: What about just doing `... WHERE email = :email`  Does it produce a result then?

Comment: You could also go into mysql command line and do:  `EXPLAIN sta402_users` and paste it in your comment.  It might shed some light on the issue

Comment: Yes, it works now. So I should DEcrypt the password ? How ?

Comment: What password hashing function are you using?

Comment: It's not encrypted, it's hashed.  A hash is a 'one-way function'.  The idea is that when a password is actually stored, it's never stored in plain text.  It's mangled into a hash via a mathematical algorithm.  The question is, why are you trying to pull out a user id by the email AND the password?  You shouldn't ever need to pull out any info from your database based on the password

Comment: @Phantomazi you kinda get it?  If not let me know.  I can probably explain it more clearly if you are confused by my last response.

Comment: Sorry, the comments just came to me. Then what do I need the password for ? I got the point of the hashing, but isn't it necessary to check the password on login ?  EDIT: i am using sha1 as hashing function.

Comment: If you're trying to check if the password they provided is correct in a login function, then you need to know the hashing algorithm used to store the hashed password.  What are you using to save passwords to the db on registration?  To make sure you understand the concept, try this from mysql directly:  `SELECT md5('secretpassword');`  I doubt you are using md5 as it's not secure anymore, but that's the idea.  So if you want to verify a login password, you hash it with the same algorithm that was used to save it, and compare the hashes.

Comment: $password = sha1( $password );
This is my code before creating the record in the db

Comment: After I reconsidered myself and read through what you've typed in few more times I think I finally got it. I think I am using the very insecure md5. 

`/*** set a form token ***/
$form_token = md5( uniqid('auth', true) );

/*** set the session form token ***/
$_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;` Am I right ?

Comment: No, that's something different.  You said it's using `$password = sha1( $password );` when it saves the password, so you just need to do the same thing to `$password` in your login verification code.  Because otherwise, you are trying to compare literally 'SECRETPASSWORD' to a sha1-hashed version of 'SECRETPASSWORD' which will always fail

Comment: Hm.. I have done this. `$password = sha1( $password );` is present both in the verification code and in the registration code. But it was failing(this is where the question came from as we figured out )

Comment: I tried to move this to a SO chat but you don't have enough 'reputation' here :( .  Anyway, what happens if you echo or print_r `$password` just before verification?  Does it match what's in the database for that email/user?

Comment: Done! Thank you! It seems that I have mistaken the passwords in some test users and i was trying to compare actually different passwords.. The explanation was great though !

Comment: Sweet!  Glad to hear it.

Comment: Can I have any contact with you for any further issues ? Somehow.

Comment: You would be better off just asking again here.  The way you worded your question was good, so next time you have an issue, just ask here again in the same way you did.